# Get response requestPermissions

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Can you please tell me how can I get the response of this function?

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, REQUEST_LOCATION);
```

Comment: Override `onRequestPermissionsResult()` in your activity. This is covered in [the documentation for `ActivityCompat.requestPermissions()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/core/app/ActivityCompat?hl=en#requestPermissions(android.app.Activity,java.lang.String[],int)).

Comment: @CommonsWare Can you add an answer with the full solution code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That code work for me..

**Step 1:** write down code in your `Activity`

- create callback of permission `requestPermissionLauncher`
- create that callback **globaly** in your `Activity`

```
private ActivityResultLauncher<String> requestPermissionLauncher =
          registerForActivityResult(new ActivityResultContracts.RequestPermission(), isGranted -> {
              if (isGranted) {
                  afterPermission(); // here you got success of permission
              } else {
                  Toast.makeText(this, "Please allow permission", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
              }
          });
```

**Step 2:** lunch permission in your `Activity`

```
//CHECK_PERMISSION_BUTTON.setOnClickListener((view -> {
    requestPermissionLauncher.launch(Manifest.permission.YOUR_PERMISSION);
//}));
```